# MySQL connection attempt times out with a local IP

Tags: mysql, portforwarding

I am trying to connect to MySQL over a local network (using --host=192.168.1.xxx), but when I try to initialize the client, I simply get no response for about 1 minute, before MySQL errors out with a generic 2003 error. My interpretation is that this means the connection attempt never ended up at the right place (so the TCP connection just times out).

The machine running MySQL Server is an ordinary laptop on Windows 10 (not running Windows Server or anything like that). I've already gone and checked the firewall rules, and port 3306 is explicitly enabled for incoming connections. Running "netstat -a -n" reveals that port 3306 on the server machine has status LISTENING. I've tried specifying port 3306, as well as port forwarding/port triggering from port 3306 to port 3306 on the router, but nothing fixes this issue. How should I get this connection to work? For reference, I am using the following command for the client:

```
mysql --host=192.168.1.34 --port=3306 --user='username' --password='password'
```

Comment: Instead of assuming that error 2003 is "generic," you should post the exact error.  There should be a number at the end corresponding to the specific Windows socket error, such as `(10060)` which would mean "Connection timed out," while other error codes would indicate other problems.

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes under the following situations:

```
  1. Client and Server, either or both of them are not in network.
  2. Server is not running.
  3. Server is running but not listening on port, client is trying to connect.
  4. Firewall is not permitted for host-port combination.
  5. Host port combination is incorrect.
```

In the above Client means your local system and server means where MySQL running machine.[To solve the problem:](http://www.javatbrains.com/2015/10/java-networking-connection-refused.html)